# Using Thrift with Java, org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException unknown result

Tags: java, rpc, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am trying to write an `RPC` with `Thrift`, the client seems to be communicating to the server just fine, and the server creates a list to return to the client (proper format). But then the client somehow cannot recognize the packet as I get this error:

> org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException: getEntityByIP failed: unknown result

This is what my thrift file looks like:

```
struct EntityLookupMessage{
1: list<i32> entityIDs;
}
service EntityJoinService {
   list<i32> getEntityByIP(1:string IPval,2:i32 date);  
}
```

And the ServerImpl is the following method:

```
public List<Integer> getEntityByIP(String IPval, int date) throws TException {
    try{
        System.out.println("Checking..."+IPval);
        List<Integer> response=EntityJoinStandalone.getEntityByIP(entityLookup,IPval, date);
        System.out.println(response);
        return response;
    }finally{
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null
    }
```

Which is called by a client like so:

```
List<Integer> entity = client.getEntityByIP(IPval, date);
```

Any ideas why this is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

Thrift by design doesn't allow for null results. This is the code of the generated recv_Xxx() function:

```
public List<Integer> recv_getEntityByIP() throws org.apache.thrift.TException
{
  getEntityByIP_result result = new getEntityByIP_result();
  receiveBase(result, "getEntityByIP");
  if (result.isSetSuccess()) {
    return result.success;
  }
  throw new org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException(  
        org.apache.thrift.TApplicationException.MISSING_RESULT, 
        "getEntityByIP failed: unknown result");
}
```

You have to return a valid result, which is ...

- a valid list, which may be empty, but must not be `null`
- an exception thrown on the server

### Solution

Remove the `return null` from your `finally` clause.

### Best practice

Put the result into an object, similar to what you already did with the args:

```
struct EntityByIP_result {
  1: list<i32> data;
}
```

This way you also leave room for further improvements down the road, you can add new fields to the `struct` at any time.

Comment: But the list isn't null. I print it before returning, and it is not null. It's [1002].

Comment: No wonder. What do you think happens in your finally branch? It doesn't matter what you print() before you return. What really matters is what you `return`, finally (pun intended).

Comment: Ahhh, ok, too rusty with my exception catching in Java.